# Codeigniter Modular HMVC extension - cant upload file

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, hmvc

I have a problem with uploading files by form. Everytime I try, I get the error "File type not allowed". I am using HMVC modular extension and my controllers extends MX_Controller.

I already tried to $var_dump($_FILES) from my form-view and the result is fine, but when I try to use method do_upload() in controller it doesnt work.

Does anyone have any idea? Here is the controller:

```
Class Store_data extends MX_Controller
```

{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function upload_pic()
{
    //$data['item_id'] = $item_id;
    $template = "bootstrap_theme";
    //$current_url = current_url();
    //$data['form_location'] = $current_url;
    $data['view_file'] = "upload_pic";
    $this->load->module('template');
    $this->template->$template($data);
}

function do_upload()
{
    //var_dump($_FILES);
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';
    $config['max_width']  = '4024';
    $config['max_height']  = '4768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->overwrite = true;
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $template = "bootstrap_theme";

        $data['view_file'] = "upload_pic";
        $this->load->module('template');
        $this->template->$template($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();
        $template = "bootstrap_theme";
        $data['view_file'] = "upload_success";
        $this->load->module('template');
        $this->template->$template($data);
    }
}
```

And here is the upload form view:

```
<?php echo $error;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('store_data/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I had to uncomment **extension=php_fileinfo.dll** in php.ini and **comment ;extension=php_mime_magic.dll**

Thanks anyway